# I just woke up one morning and my iPhone 3GS had the glass on its coverface cracked?

Tags: iphone

I just woke up one morning and my iPhone 3GS had the glass on its coverface cracked?!!?  I had a friend who has a PhD in Physics from Stanford tell me this is due to a flaw in the manufacture of the screen causing a very low/cold temperature to crack the screen.  Has anyone else had this happen and gotten Apple to replace their phone?

Comment: one other thought would be if somethig's wrong with the battery, it could push up on the screen and cause it to crack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the same thing happened to me and they said they had seen it before from a certain batch of iPhones.

Answer (score 6):

Visit Apple Store and ask for a free repair.

Comment: Not ask, demand :p